# Aguardar resposta AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, popup, alertdialog

Eu tenho uma aplicação android com uma tela inicial, onde tem um [listview](/questions/tagged/listview), e quando clico no item do [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) ela abre um [alertdialog](/questions/tagged/alertdialog), que exibi a seguinte mensagem *"Deseja Iniciar Manutenção ?"*, e possui dois botões *"SIM"* e *"NÂO"*, se o usuario cliacar em *"SIM"*, então ele deveria abrir outra tela e passar os parametros de *"position"* que estão no *onItemClick*, se o usuário clicar em *NÂO* manter-se na mesma tela, como posso fazer ?

```js
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder msgBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    msgBox.setTitle("Atenção!");
    msgBox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame);
    msgBox.setMessage("Deseja iniciar Manutenção na ETE?");
    msgBox.setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Cliente cliente = adpClientes.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, init_manutencao.class);
            intent.putExtra("CLIENTE", cliente);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    msgBox.setNegativeButton("NÂO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saindo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    msgBox.create();
    msgBox.show();
}
```

Comment: Quando você fala _"aguardar a resposta do AlertDialog"_ você se refere ao evento de clique do `AlertDialog`?

Comment: sim, ele deveria aguardar o usuário clicar em sim, se ele clicar em sim ele passa pra próxima tela, se ele clicar em não continua na mesma tela.

Comment: mas eu também tenho alguns parâmetros de posição no meu onItemClick, que só devem ser passados se o usuário clicar em sim

Comment: O `AlertDialog` abre ou apenas não faz nada ao clique do botão?

Comment: a AlertDialog abre, e pergunta se o usuário quer seguir para próxima fase.

Comment: Para evitar discussões extensas sobre o problema, edite sua pergunta e torne-a mais especifica indicando possíveis mensagens de erro ou o comportamento não esperado do código

Comment: Alterei a pergunta conforme sua recomendação Ivan, por gentileza se puder ajudar, eu serei grato.

Comment: Não entendo a sua dúvida. Se quer que algo seja feito quando o botão "SIM" for clicado, o código que faz esse "algo" deve ser colocado no local onde está `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Iniciando Manutenção", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: note que estou chamando o alertDialog no meu _public void onItemClick_ logo abaixo eu tenho a chamada de tela, porem eu preciso aguardar que o usuário clique em SIM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá, Leonardo!

Se entendi bem seu problema, podemos resolvê-lo da seguinte forma

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder msgBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            msgBox.setTitle("Atenção!");
            msgBox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame);
            msgBox.setMessage("Deseja iniciar Manutenção na ETE?");
            msgBox.setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     Cliente cliente = adpClientes.getItem(position);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAtual.this, ActivityQueRecebeOsDados.class);
                            intent.putExtra("CLIENTE", cliente);
                     startActivity(intent);
               }
            });
            msgBox.setNegativeButton("NÂO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saindo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            });
            msgBox.create();
            msgBox.show();
    }
```

Tomei a liberdade de reestruturar seu código excluído a função `Popup()` e criando o `AlertDialog` diretamente dentro do evento de clique do item.

Como salientei no início, se entendi, você deseja capturar o objeto cliente na posição do clique e mandar esse dado para outra `Activity` (tela, como disse). Para tal,

1 - Você precisa passar seu dado `Cliente`, que é um objeto, via `Intent`

2 - Envia o `Intent` chamando `startActivity(Intent i)` e não `startAcivityForResult`

3 - Para recuperar o objeto na outra `Activity`, em `onCreate`, faça
`

```
    Cliente client;
    if(getIntent() != null) {
       client = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("CLIENTE");
    }
```

**Atenção: é preciso que seu objeto `Cliente` implemente a interface `Parcelable`**

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu havia tentado desta maneira porém obtive erro pois não estava passando o ActivityAtual, e estava recebendo erro pois position não era acessivel dentro do onClick. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Fico que feliz que consegui lhe ajudar. Boa sorte!